# Transactions não funciona em criações/modificações de estruturas?

Tags: mysql, transações

Estava procurando na internet se havia alguma maneira de executar *Transactions* para operações do tipo `ALTER TABLE` ou `CREATE TABLE` no *Mysql*. Isso porque em um sistema nosso, usamos Migrations e queria que, se alguma coisa desse errado na criação da tabela, as alterações tivessem um rollback.

Acabei descobrindo que **não é possível** fazer isso em Mysql.

Vi isso nessa [Resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20420600/laravel-migration-transaction) do SOEN.

(Se alguém puder traduzir, ficarem grato, mas deu pra entender mais ou menos).

> Some statements cannot be rolled back. In general, these include data definition language (DDL) statements, such as those that create or drop databases, those that create, drop, or alter tables or stored routines.

Mas daí ficaram algumas dúvidas :

- Sabendo que não são todos os *Statments* que suportam *Rollback*, quais são eles que sempre são aceitos?
- Por que existe essa limitação quanto as alterações estruturais das tabelas?

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cannot-roll-back.html) do MySQL fala, no geral comandos de DDL(create, alter, drop, trucante) não são suportados dentro de transações, pois a sua execução causa um commit de forma [implicita](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) ou seja uma vez executada a instrução sua aplicação é feita no banco na hora em caso de sucesso.

Normalmente o conceito de transação é aplicado a manipulação(fazer/desfazer) dos dados, alguns bancos permitem algumas DDL em trasanções conforme [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4692690/1342547).